# SSL query - CSR for certificate renewal

Tags: ssl, key, private, public

Need the understanding about SSL and the way it functions. Kindly help answer the below.

I understand that the CSR that we generate has our public key and DN info i.e C=,CN=,L=,O=,OU=,ST=.

Are both these two compoments (JPMC public key and the DN) hashed and if the hash is also send to verisign at the time we request them for a cert (new cert or a cert renewal).

What amount these (public key, DN and the hash) are encrypted using JPMC's private key.

Does Verisign (CA) use the public key that we send them as part of the CSR or do they have it from other means inorder to decrypt whatever was encrypted above.

Answer (score 1):

No, the information in a certificate signing request is not hashed - how could it be - you can't get the information back after hashing? It is not encrypted either, none of the information is sensitive.

A CSR contains the version of the PKCS#10 standard which is being used, the DN of the entity the certificate is for, the public key that will be used, and optionally, some attributes such as subject alternate names, etc.

The CSR is signed, using the private key generated to initiate the request (or, in renewal, the private key of the existing certificate).

[PKCS#10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986) is the main specification for all of this.

Comment: When you are renewing a certificate, you can (and should) change the private/public keypair as well.